# How to do Projection in "GraphQL.Net"?

Tags: asp.net-core, graphql, selection, projection, graphql.net

I have problem with using GraphQL.Net, and that is what I need.
I specify four fields in a`Type Class`, when I try to fetch only two fields with a query on GraphQL, the executing query on database contains all four fields that defined in `Type class` but I expect query to be something look like this : 
`Select field1,field2 from someEntity`

**How to do this projection ?!** 
I'm using GraphQL.Net version 7.2.2

Comment: Where do you want to get the data for the two fields specified. Query the specified field in the C# code or in the playground?